# Exception object printed as null in the logger

Tags: java, exception

I have a method which has to catch an exception.
There was bug in the production and
when I was going through the log file
I found something strange.
There seems to be an exception,
when I searched for the catch block where I printed exception object by implementing toString(),
I found that the object printed as null.
I found 2 or 3 links but there's never a clear answer.
Below is my method and logger.

```
public void downloadFile() throws ServletException, IOException
{
    try{
        //some logic to download a  file
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        setRetMessage("File cannot be download.");   
        PAYTFFileDebug.trace("Error in download >>>>>>>>> "+e.toString(),PAYTFFileDebug.LEVEL_5);
    }
}
```

below is the log in which i found something which is not usual.

`Fri Jan 27 14:50:13 GMT+05:30 2015 : Level 5:Error in download >>>>>>>>> null`

Comment: Try `e.getMessage()`

Comment: Thats an unusual one, it implies that `e.toString()` is returning null.  Do you have your own exception classes that implement toString?  In any case have you tried running locally in debug mode and putting a break point at that location?

Comment: @Ascalonian Thanks. That i will try but what i  want to know the reason for null exception object.

Comment: It's not a `null` exception object. It's the `toString()` method returning `null`. In fact if `e` was `null` that call would throw a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: @JaimieWhiteside No. I don't have own exception classes as it is a normal download. Actually there's no need of one. The bug itself seems very strange. What method does is picks up a file from a server location , zips it and gets downloaded on the browser. In this case file is available on the location, but when i try to download that file struts page on which this utility is available, goes blank page.  Everything is fine as far i tracked.

Comment: @DanAllen In every simple method, exceptions are caught in this way in whole application. I never got a null exception object. I have tracked so many bugs in the same fashion. Always exception reference got me some exception. Is there anything wrong to catch the exceptions in this way??

Comment: Try something like `"Error in download >>>>>>>>> ("+e.getClass().toString()+") "+e.toString()`. `e` clearly isn't `null` and no (standard or conformant) exception class returns `null` from that method.

Comment: @Naveen. You haven't got a `null` exception object yet. You've got a non-`null` exception object returning `null` from its `toString()` method. That's a different thing. There's nothing wrong with handling exceptions this way. However something funny is going on in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically you would want to log the stack trace of the Exception.  I cannot tell which underlying logging framework you are using but most would allow you to pass a Throwable after the message.  For example in Log4J we have:

```
public void error(Object message,
     Throwable t)
```

If your logging framework supports it can you try:

```
PAYTFFileDebug.error("Error in download.", e);
```

This will ensure that you log the complete stack trace of that exception and can then better troubleshoot the problem.

Comment: logger is user defined. No other frame work is used.

Comment: Even if it user defined it is of a particular type that your code accepts.